# Identity Server - Oauth2 userinfo / Missing Field named Expires

Tags: oauth, wso2, token, identity, wso2-identity-server

Is there a configuration option in the WSO2 Identity server to define a set of customized claim values for the scope "openid" and to add the current token expiry in seconds. This counter named "expires" could be helpful to track and renew ageing tokens, before they move into an expired  state. I currently see the following values returning from the "userinfo" query:

```
{"phone_number":"+55xxxxxxx","email":"xxxxxx@br.red.com","name":"xxxxx","xxxxxxxxx":"xxxxxxxxx","preferred_username":"xxxxxx","given_name":"xxxxx","country":"Brazil"}
```

Comment: This question is still open. Does anybody know how to add the Oauth 2.0 token expiry counter, a steadily decreasing numeric value in seconds and integrate it as a claim making it visible at the Oauth 2.0 "userinfo" query?

Comment: Any recommendation about best practice for tracking of the Oauth 2.0 Token expiry using a WSO2 server? 

 Is it recommended to implement an application based control task, which relies on the "expires-in" counter value received at the initial token emission, or is it doable to use one, or multiple a "userinfo" look-up function to fetch the current time span missing until expiry of the valid "token" and by this to organize a cyclic renewal, based on an exchange of a refresh token when the access token gets close to its expiry?